# Definition of finite dimensional representation of Lie group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

My main source of reference is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group.

According to this link, if $G$ is a Lie group and $V$ a finite dimensional complex vector space, then we say that $(\pi,V)$ is a representation of $G$ if $\pi:G\to GL(V)$ is a smooth group homomorphism.

It is remarked that smoothness is a technicality, in that any continuous homomorphism will automatically be smooth.

The article then proceeds to say that can alternatively describe a representation of a Lie group $G$ as a linear action of $G$ on a vector space $V$. This is the part I am unsure of.

If we have such a linear action (say $\cdot)$, then I can see that $\pi:G\to GL(V)$ defined by $\pi(g)(v)=g\cdot v$ is a group homomorphism. However, why is smoothness satisfied? I suppose it suffices to show continuity, but this still does not seem clear to me.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: In the case wikipedia is incorrect, would additional assumptions on $G$ (e.g. compactness) make the above definition correct?

Comment: I think the "action" part of "linear action" is assuming that the action is continuous. Otherwise (assuming the axiom of choice) there are non-continuous representations of Lie groups. For example, you could take one of the "wild" solutions to Cauchy's functional equation (a discontinuous $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$), and compose it with the exponential to get a discontinuous function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \operatorname{GL}_1(\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = \exp(f(x))$, satisfying $g(x + y) = g(x) g(y)$.

Comment: Compactness is not enough, but if $G$ is a real simple Lie group then each homomorphism to $GL(n,R)$ is automatically continuous. As a general rule, you should not trust wikipedia too much, use it only as a starting point.